# How do I change heading for turtles after every movement they make in Netlogo?

Tags: netlogo

In my model I have turtles moving from the right side of the map to the left side. As they travel through they are looking for green patches. When they find one and it is in their cone of vision they turn and head towards it. If there are multiple patches that are equidistant they choose at random which one to go to. However, as they move across there seems to be a lot of unnecessary jitter in their movement. Anyone able to tell why? Peek this picture https://i.stack.imgur.com/c9elI.jpg. They should be heading straight until they see green.

```
to move-bug

    ask bugs [
    count-steps
    if pxcor = min-pxcor [
    file-open data-filename
    file-type data-filename
    file-type " "
    file-type  data-header
    file-write vision-width
    file-write vision-distance
    file-write greenroof-percent
    file-write gray-steps
    file-write green-steps
    file-write steps
    file-type "\n"
    file-close
      ]

     if pxcor = min-pxcor [die]

     set heading 270
     pen-down
     let green_target nobody
     let perceived_patches patches in-cone vision-distance vision-width
     set green_target perceived_patches with [ pcolor = green ]
    ifelse count green_target > 0 [face min-one-of green_target [vision-                 distance]][face min-one-of perceived_patches [vision-distance]] ;; added equivalent jitter to non-green squares
```

forward 1
         ]

```
   end
```

Answer (score 1):

Every time a bug moves, it will run your `ifelse count green_target` block. `Ifelse` will run one of the two command blocks you have given it, so each time this procedure runs the bug faces either a green target patch (if green patches are within its cone of vision) or a perceived patch (if **no** green patches are visible to the bug). Therefore, if your procedure that moves the bug is called after `move-bug`, the bug will jitter since its heading changes due to whichever `face` line is run before it actually moves. What you actually want is for the bug to only face a patch if there is a green one in sight, so try just using an if statement instead of an ifelse. Additionally, you are using

`min-one-of green_target [vision-distance]`

but you may want

`min-one-of green_target [distance myself]`

to select the closest green patch. I got the code below to work for me, with the caveat that I just randomly placed green circles on my field ([see image- bugs here move right to left](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8i6aa.png)).

```
  set heading 270
  pd       ;; shorthand for pen-down
  let green_target nobody
  let perceived_patches patches in-cone vision-distance vision-width 
  set green_target perceived_patches with [ pcolor = green ]
  print green_target
  if count green_target > 0 [
    face min-one-of green_target [ distance myself ]
  ]

  fd 1
```

Comment: Thank you so much!